# adding resolution with xrandr

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xrandr

I added `newmode` with `xrandr` by typing `moduline`, but it added on another output service like DVI-I-3.

It says that this line is disconnected. So I want to add this resolution on DVI-I-0 or change it with DVI-I-3.

Whats is solution?

I can't output this resolution.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1360 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00 +
   1360x768      59.96*   59.80  
   1152x864      60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1920x1080_60.00 (0x287) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock  67.16KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock  59.96Hz
```

Answer (score 1):

It's explained on the following Wiki page for example: [Adding undetected resolutions | ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, can you summarize?